# How to sort data ASC by total count of word in Mongodb in codeigniter PHP 7.3

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, codeigniter, php-7.3

I'm looking for a query which returns all exact matches first followed by rows that contain one or more words of the search string ordered by word count.

If a users searches for a the word "Banana" the query should return all rows that contain only "Banana", followed by "Banana" +1 word then "Banana" +2 words and so on.

Example 1:

Search "Banana":

1. List item
2. Banana
3. Banana Split
4. Banana Cakes
5. Banana Cream Biscuits
6. ...

Example 2:

Search "Banana Cakes":

1. List item
2. Banana Cakes
3. Banana
4. Cakes
5. Banana Split
6. Chocolate Cakes
7. Banana Cream Biscuits
8. ...

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work so far? What's the actual programming problem you are facing?

Comment: I have tried a pipeline. but the aggregate function is not working. its returning error like - "Message: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$tbl_food"